# Pass variable from custom hook to TPL file

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have created a custom module. Which simply registers a hook, whose only function is to obtain a list of products of a specific category.

The hook works perfectly. Then I call it from a TPL file, it is called correctly, but when I try to get the hook variable from the TPL file, I can't.

This is the code of my Hook.

```
    public function hookDisplayCaronteCategories($params){

        if (array_key_exists('max', $params)) {
            $max = $params['max'];
        }
        else{
            $max = 1000;
        }

        $category = new Category(
            $params['id_category'], //id de la categoría
            (int)Context::getContext()->language->id // id del idioma
        );
        $caronteProducts = $category->getProducts(
            (int)Context::getContext()->language->id, //id lenguaje
             1, //número de páginas
             $max, //productos por páginas
             'date_add', //order by
             'DESC', //order way
             false, //get total
             true, //mostrar activos
             false, // random
             1, // random_number_products
             true, //check access
             Context::getContext() //context
        );
        $this->smarty->assign(array('caronteProducts', $caronteProducts));
        return $this->display('http://localhost/rapture/themes/classic_child/templates/cms/page-6.tpl');
    }
```

The var_dump function at the end correctly displays the product data.

[image]

However, if I do a var_dump from the tpl, the function returns null. This is how I call the hook from the tpl.

```
      {hook h="displayCaronteCategories" id_category=11}
      {$caronteProducts|var_dump}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

How can I get the hook variable in the tpl file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in which TPL are you trying to print the **$caronteProducts** variable ?

You'll need to fetch/render your TPL inside your hook, and the variable will be available there as there is no global scope..

Something like :

```
$this->smarty->assign(array('caronteProducts', $caronteProducts));
return $this->display(dirname(__FILE__), 'views/templates/hook/caronteproducts.tpl');
```

Comment: I am trying to do it in a custom TPL of a CMS, in '/themes/child/cms/page6.tpl'.
I am calling the hook from the TPL itself, using the code {hook h="displayCaronteCategories" id_category=11}.

If I declare the TPL inside the hook, will this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: I have this now:
$this->smarty->assign(array('caronteProducts', $caronteProducts));
return $this->display('http://localhost/rapture/themes/classic_child/templates/cms/page-6.tpl');
But I can't get it to work

Comment: Update: I have managed to make it work by saving the variable in session, as follows:
        $this->smarty->assign(array('caronteProducts', $caronteProducts));
        $_SESSION['caronteProducts'] = $caronteProducts;
        session_commit();
Then in the TPL I collect the smarty.session variable, with this it works, but I don't know if it is the most appropriate.

Comment: This is quite hacky , just follow my answer's solution and include the TPL you want to display INSIDE the module so when you call {hook h="displayCaronteCategories"} inside your CMS , it will be already rendered with your neeed variable.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests around the issue
the trouble is there :

```
$this->smarty->assign(array('caronteProducts', $caronteProducts));
```

It should be :

```
$this->smarty->assign(array('caronteProducts' => $caronteProducts));
```